# Only display a shader at a certain height

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I followed this tutorial for grass https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHe7N42zE1k and in the end I drag and drop a shader on a mesh and it makes grass display. I want the grass to only start displaying at a certain height.

[Terrain Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmF97.png)

In the picture above you can see that grass gets placed underwater from this method. So can you decide where to start a shader depending on height?

Answer (score 0):

In the geometry shader (Grass.shader), it emits blade all the time:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < BLADE_SEGMENTS; i++)
    {
        float t = i / (float)BLADE_SEGMENTS;

        float segmentHeight = height * t;
        float segmentWidth = width * (1 - t);
        float segmentForward = pow(t, _BladeCurve) * forward;

        // Select the facing-only transformation matrix for the root of the blade.
        float3x3 transformMatrix = i == 0 ? transformationMatrixFacing : transformationMatrix;

        triStream.Append(GenerateGrassVertex(pos, segmentWidth, segmentHeight, segmentForward, float2(0, t), transformMatrix));
        triStream.Append(GenerateGrassVertex(pos, -segmentWidth, segmentHeight, segmentForward, float2(1, t), transformMatrix));
    }

    // Add the final vertex as the tip.
    triStream.Append(GenerateGrassVertex(pos, 0, height, forward, float2(0.5, 1), transformationMatrix));
```

You can add a condition here to tell your GS not to emit if position is below a certain threshold.

```
if (pos.y > minHeightThreshold)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < BLADE_SEGMENTS; i++)
    {
        float t = i / (float)BLADE_SEGMENTS;

        float segmentHeight = height * t;
        float segmentWidth = width * (1 - t);
        float segmentForward = pow(t, _BladeCurve) * forward;

        // Select the facing-only transformation matrix for the root of the blade.
        float3x3 transformMatrix = i == 0 ? transformationMatrixFacing : transformationMatrix;

        triStream.Append(GenerateGrassVertex(pos, segmentWidth, segmentHeight, segmentForward, float2(0, t), transformMatrix));
        triStream.Append(GenerateGrassVertex(pos, -segmentWidth, segmentHeight, segmentForward, float2(1, t), transformMatrix));
    }

    // Add the final vertex as the tip.
    triStream.Append(GenerateGrassVertex(pos, 0, height, forward, float2(0.5, 1), transformationMatrix));
}
```